Color de fondo transparente en tkinter
Estoy creando mi interfaz en python con tkinter y estoy utilizando como fondo una imágen.
Tengo mi siguiente label:
tk.Label(root, text="Bienvenidos", font=('Arial', 16), bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#4B2E05').pack(pady=10)

Y el problema que tengo es con el fondo del label, quiero que sea transparente para que no interfiera con mi fondo.

Si quieres poner un foondo balnco usa attributes(), como por ejemplo el ejemplo que te dejo haze que se vea transparente:
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.config(bg="grey")

root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "grey")



root.mainloop()

Esto va a crear una pantalla transparente.

Gracias por responder, tu código hace que el fondo de la interfaz sea transparente, pero yo quiero que el fondo del label sea transparente, para que no interfiera con mi fondo, que es una imagen.
